# His most attractive trait/s was/were his eyes

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I'm confused about the requirements of singular/plural in the given sentence.

> His most attractive trait was his eyes

vs

> His most attractive traits were his eyes

Eyes is a plural word, however, it is only a single trait in this context. Do I need to use plural or singular here?

Comment: *Trait → is*; *traits → were*. The subject is *trait*, not *eyes*.

Comment: Yes, but my problem is, that eyes itself is plural. So is it a single trait, or does it count as multiple (two) traits?

Comment: It doesn't matter. *My **problem is** that (my three cars were red and two of them broke down).* There is only **one** trait here—his eyes. *His most attractive **trait was** that (his eyes were blue).* The verb *only* agrees with the singularly or plurality of the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trait seems to be the wrong word here to begin with. A trait refers to a certain quality of a person. I think `feature`is a much more suitable word used in your sentence- and I would use the singular form of that word.

> His most attractive feature was his eyes.

Comment: Thanks for the correction with feature, you're certainly right. But why do you choose the singular form here, when it's not a singular eye, but plural?

Comment: Can you imagine thinking that someone's left eye was slightly more attractive than their right?